# How to run an apache server in custom vpc(non default)aws through terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I created a custom vpc in aws through terraform with 1 public subnet and 2 private subnet.Now i need to launch an instance running apache in private subnet through Terraform.My code to launch an instance in private subnet is this

```
resource "aws_instance" "my_apache" {
    ami = "ami-8437a5e4"
    key_name = "clust"
    subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.my_private1.id}"
    vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-40542d3b"]
    availability_zone = "us-west-2a"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    tags {
      Name = "apache"
      }
      provisioner "remote-exec" {
        inline = [
          "sudo apt-get update",
          "sudo apt-get install apache2",
          "sudo service apache2 start"
        ]
      }
}
```

The instance is launching but apache server is not running in the instance.I am getting the error like dis.

```
aws_instance.my_apache (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
aws_instance.my_apache (remote-exec):   Host: 172.16.2.163
aws_instance.my_apache (remote-exec):   User: root
aws_instance.my_apache (remote-exec):   Password: false
aws_instance.my_apache (remote-exec):   Private key: false
aws_instance.my_apache (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: true
aws_instance.my_apache: Still creating... (3m0s elapsed)
^CInterrupt received. Gracefully shutting down...
aws_instance.my_apache: Still creating... (3m10s elapsed)
aws_instance.my_apache (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
aws_instance.my_apache (remote-exec):   Host: 172.16.2.163
aws_instance.my_apache (remote-exec):   User: root
aws_instance.my_apache (remote-exec):   Password: false
aws_instance.my_apache (remote-exec):   Private key: false
aws_instance.my_apache (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: true
```

It keeps on continuing.

What could be the issue?.How to make apache run in that instance?

Comment: What sort of connectivity do you have from where you're running terraform?  It looks like it doesn't have access into the private subnet in order to connect to your instance in order to run the provisioning

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are creating your instance in private subnet so please make sure you have connectivity to your instance from the machine you are running terraform.

Second thing your logs are specifying:

```
aws_instance.my_apache (remote-exec):   Password: false
aws_instance.my_apache (remote-exec):   Private key: false
```

Use provisnors connection:

```
 connection {
    type     = "ssh"
    user     = "root"
    private_key = "${var.private_key}"
}
```

Refer: https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/connection.html